# How to find an object from a list based on object member value

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ I want to find an object in the list if the object member matches the specific value.

```
class gate{
 public: 
  std::string type;
} 

class netlist {
  std::list<gate *> gates_;
  void identify_out_gate();
}
```

Now I want to find a particular gate from the list based on its type. I am using the following:

```
netlist::identify_out_gate()
{
    for (std::list<gate *>::const_iterator out_gate = gates_.begin(); out_gate != gates_.end(); ++out_gate)
    {
        if((*out_gate)->type == "output")
        {
            //do something......
        }
    }
}
```

but I want to know if I can use something like find or find_if and how?

Comment: `find` and `find_if` are part of the C++ standard. I suggest you **first** try solve your problem by your self, for example by consulting [this excellent resource](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Answer (score 3):

Sure. For example:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(gates_.begin(),
                         gates_.end  (),
                         [](gate const *g) { return g->type == "output"); });
```

`iter` is going to have type `std::list<gate*>::iterator`.

Note that this only finds one element. To find the next one, use `find_if(iter + 1, gates_.end(), ...)`. Also, be sure to check that `iter != gates_.end()`, because if `iter == gates_.end()`, then nothing was found.

Comment: Hi Wintermute, thanks for your reply but when I implemented this I gpt this error " error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token" ..Am i missing anything?

Comment: Your compiler has to know C++11 for the lambda closure. If you're working with gcc or clang, pass it -std=c++11 (or -std=c++0x, if you're using an old version). If you don't want to use C++11 (although you should!), you can use a function `bool is_output_gate(gate const *g) { return g->type == "output"; }` and `is_output_gate` instead of the lambda.